# Can't connect to Cassandra using Datastax DevCenter

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have Cassandra set up in docker, and I'm able run cql queries against it, I'm also able to connect to it through my node.js application, but the Datastax DevCenter app I just installed (for Mac) is not able to connect (see image).

[image]

Comment: what is the error you are getting now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove "http://../" as part of the contact host.Only 127.0.0.1 is enough.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still not able to connect after doing that EDIT: nvm it worked!